# Не могу передвинуть курсор в интерпретаторе питона

Tags: python, ubuntu

Не могу передвинуть курсор в интерпретаторе питона, заходя через командную строку. Появляются совокупности символов вида "`^[[A`".
Например, нажимаю поочередно Up, Down, Right, Left:

```
dzmitry@mycomp:~$ py
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul  9 2016, 03:29:05) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^[[A^[[B^[[C^[[D
```

Операционная система: Ubuntu 14.04. В командной строке операционной системы все работает хорошо

Comment: попробуйте Ctrl +  + Shift + Up, Down, Right, Left

Comment: Попробовал. При Нажатии Ctrl + Shift + Left появляется ^[[1;6D и так далее

Comment: а что такое *py*? приведите вывод `$ type py`

Comment: dzmitry@mycomp:~$ type py
py is aliased to `python3'

Comment: а программа сама откуда взялась? [в репозиториях в настоящий момент такого пакета нет](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

Comment: Скачал с https://www.python.org/downloads/ и поставил

Comment: @pynix, ну, тогда пишите им багрепорт: 1. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interactive.html 2. https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#rlcompleter-config // а на будущее постарайтесь не использовать в системе левых пакетов и самосборных программ.

Comment: Вроде бы python.org официальный дом питона. Какие левые пакеты?

Comment: @pynix, левые - которые НЕ из репозитория дистрибутива. Да, питон.орг официальный сайт питона, но тамошний setup.py не учитывает всех компонентов и их версий той же бубунты. Отсюда могут возникать такие вот проблемы.

Comment: Так что делать? Сносить 3.5.2 и ставить то, что есть в репозитарии? Просто не хочется, я когда 3.4.2 сносил то убунту перестала загружаться

Comment: @pynix, да, попробовать на родных версия библиотек. Если заработает (при условии, что мусора от новых версий не осталось) - значит просто несовместимость.

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Seeing escape characters when pressing the arrow keys in python shell](http://stackoverflow.com/q/893053/4279)

Comment: Ставьте 3.4.2 из репозиториев и не сносите больше ничего :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы видите текстовое представление [ANSI кодов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI) в терминале вместо соответствующих движений курсора в интерактивном режиме, то это указывает что `python` был скомпилирован без поддержки `readline`.

Убедитесь, что `libreadline-dev` Ubuntu пакет у вас установлен, перед компиляцией `python` из исходников. Простой способ поставить все зависимости это выполнить:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep python python3
```

Чтобы автоматизировать компиляцию различных версий с python.org, удобно использовать [`pythonz`](http://saghul.github.io/pythonz/) (или [`pyenv`](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv), [conda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html#install-a-different-version-of-python)):

```
$ pythonz install 3.5.2    # install
$ $(pythonz locate 3.5.2)  # run
```

Не пытайтесь заменить системный python — это не нужно (как пример с pythonz показывает) и может сломать системные утилиты, реализованные на Питоне (такие как сам `apt-get`). В системные области ставьте пакеты исключительно через `apt-get`.

---

В НЕ интерактивном режиме это нормально, что стрелочки не работают:

```
$ python3 -c 'input()'
^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A
```

Если `readline` модуль загружен, то [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) автоматически его использует (стрелочки/история итд работают):

```
$ python3 -c 'import readline; input()'
# стрелочки работают
```

В интерактивном режиме `readline` загружается автоматически:

```
$ python3 -i -c 'input()' # неявный readline импорт
# стрелочки работают
```

Если просто запустить `python3`, то запускается REPL, что является интерактивным режимом, и соответственно стрелочки обязаны работать, если `python3` был собран правильно.

---

Для создания своих интерактивных программ в Питоне (таких как [xonsh](http://xon.sh/), [ipython](http://github.com/ipython/ipython/), [http-prompt](https://github.com/eliangcs/http-prompt)), можно использовать [`prompt_toolkit` модуль](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/prompt_toolkit) — минимально он может выполнять роль `readline` (и больше).